# How to replace the string value with slashes in an array while querying into mongodb?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I am trying to store the array value coming from html in the server side mongodb. the array is coming in the form of strings ie for example ["home","sports"] but i need to store in the form of slash array ie [/home/,/sports/]. i tried with using replace function in javascript but i failed doing that.

Here is my code what I tried: in my server side controller:

```
 var sample = [];
    sampleArray = ["home","sports"]; //coming from html search query.

    if(sampleArray != 0){
    for (var i = 0; i < sampleArray .length; i++) {
          var eg3 = sampleArray [i];
          console.log('value form an array' + eg3);
          sample.push(eg3);

        }
      var test = sample.replace(/"/g, "/");
    }

    // querying my DB
    mongoQuery = {
          ProCat: {
            $elemMatch: {
              "title": {
                $in: test //expected output [/home/,/sports/] but i am getting ["home","sports"]
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert a String Array to RegEx array, you can use [RegEx constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and Array [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

es6:

```js
const regexArray = ["home","sports"].map(x=>new RegExp(x));

console.log(regexArray);
```

es5 code [converted online](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=const%20regexArray%20%3D%20%5B%22home%22%2C%22sports%22%5D.map(x%3D%3Enew%20RegExp(x))%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(regexArray)%3B)

```
"use strict";

var regexArray = ["home", "sports"].map(function (x) {
  return new RegExp(x);
});

console.log(regexArray);
```

Comment: can you please explain me in detail what it wiil do map(x=> new RegExp(x)) @sabithpocker

Comment: thanks now it is clear and also got the result too @sabithpocker